# Как лучше реализовать такие блоки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать такие блоки на css? первая картинка обычное состояния, вторая - состояние :hover на левый блок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Советую копать в сторону `transform`, а именно при наведении один блок уменьшать по х, другой увеличивать. Кнопку (ссылку для каждого блока свою) можно абсолютно позиционировать с `displey: none` и при наведении показывать. В полоске с текстом использовать несколько спанов....... Вариантов много на самом деле

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/j2tku1rz/

Comment: опишите задачу подробнее, пожалуйста. Я правильно понимаю, при ховере на ссылкуа увеличить ширину, убрать размытие фона и показать кнопку?

Comment: да, при ховере на конкретный блок(левый или правый) он "раскрывается", показывается кнопка и убирается размытие фона. Проблема при создании блока именно такой формы + наведение должно срабатывать только на этом блокe учитывая диагональный срез

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, интересная задача. Вот мое решение:

[Кодперо](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/vGjPJM?editors=1100)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100&subset=cyrillic,latin);
 body {
  font: 36px/1'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 3;
}
img {
  width: 130%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  object-fit: fill;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.container a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
}
a.block-left {
  width: 65%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  left: 0;
}
a.block-right {
  width: 65%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 45% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  right: 0;
}
.block-left-div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 65%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
}
p.block-left {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 0;
  color: #fafafa;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.block-left-div img {
  right: 10%;
}
.block-right-div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 65%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 45% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%);
}
p.block-right {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.block-right-div img {
  right: 10%;
}
/* hover */

a.block-left:hover ~ p.block-left {
  width: 75%;
}
a.block-left:hover,
a.block-left:hover ~ .block-left-div {
  width: 75%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 65% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 65% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 65% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 65% 100%);
}
a.block-left:hover ~ .block-right-div {
  width: 55%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 54% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 54% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 54% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 54% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
a.block-left:hover ~ p.block-right {
  width: 25%;
}
a.block-left:hover ~ .block-left-div img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0);
}
a.block-left:hover ~ p.block-left:after {
  content: 'подробнее о котиках...';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 33%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
a.block-right:hover ~ p.block-right {
  width: 75%;
}
a.block-right:hover ~ .block-left-div {
  width: 55%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 45% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 45% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 45% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 45% 100%);
}
a.block-right:hover ~ .block-right-div {
  width: 76%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 40% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 40% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 40% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 40% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
a.block-right:hover ~ p.block-left {
  width: 25%;
}
a.block-right:hover ~ .block-right-div img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0);
  bottom: 50%;
}
a.block-right:hover ~ p.block-right:after {
  content: 'подробнее о кроликах...';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 33%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="block-left"></a>
    <a href="##" class="block-right"></a>
    <p class="block-left">Котики</p>
    <p class="block-right">Кролики</p>
    <div class="block-left-div">
      <img src="http://www.velvet.by/files/userfiles/19083/ekrk.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="block-right-div">
      <img src="http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/zabavnie_jivotnie/kroliki_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" />
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

парочка статей в помощь, а так - гуглите polygonal div
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368404/how-to-create-a-polygon-shape-div
https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/
для анимации ищите использование свойств transition\transform

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно примерно сделать:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
.text {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
.left-text {
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
.right-text {
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 200px;
}
.blok1 {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewX(-40deg) translateX(-50%);
    transition:  all .5s ease;
}
.blok2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewX(-40deg)  translateX(50%);
    transition:  all .5s ease;
}
.blok2:hover{
    transform: skewX(-40deg)  translateX(30%);
}
.blok2:hover .link2 {
    display: block;
    left: 100px;
}
.blok1:hover {
    transform: skewX(-40deg)  translateX(-40%);
    z-index: 2
}
.blok1:hover .link1{
    display: block;
    right: 100px;
}

.link {
    display: none;
    height: 40px;
    background: lightpink;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightslategray;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: skewX(40deg)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="text">
           <span class="left-text">текст</span>
           <span class="right-text">текст</span> 
        </span>
        <div class="blok1">
            <a href="#" class="link link1">подробнее</a>
        </div>
        <div class="blok2">
            <a href="#" class="link link2">подробнее</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если еще по колдовать с фоном и размытием думаю у Вас все получиться.